# Unable to Access Filab Instace via SSH

Tags: fiware, filab

I have followed [this guide](https://github.com/iblancasa/FIWARE-cloud-tuto) (the only difference I noticed is that in the guide there is no "network selection" step, but I selected one when creating the instance).

I have already created a security group with all ports open (TCP, UDP and ICMP), the Keypair and the floating IP. The problem is that I can not even `ping` the floating IP, which is currently assigned to a running instance. Therefore, I am unable to access it via SSH.

I am working with Spain2. The floating IP is `130.206.114.76`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to take a look to this presentation [Setting up your virtual infrastructure using FIWARE Lab cloud](http://www.slideshare.net/flopezaguilar/setting-up-your-virtual-infrastructure-using-fi-lab-cloud-32388357). Due to you are using a region in which you need to specify a netowrk when you deploy a virtual machine.

If you have any problem in the process send an email to the support team fiware-lab-help@list.fi-ware.org